# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i'm trying to make a small system filtering in laravel using the following function in my controller to filter users by their roles or their names here's my current code:

**profilecontroller.php:**

```
public function membrevis()
{
    $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;
    $users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('users.valid','=',0)
        ->select('users.*','roles.description');
   if ($filter != null) {
        $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
            ->orWhere('roles.description',' like','%'.$filter.'%');
   }
   $users->get();

   return view('membre2',['users'=> $users]); 
}
```

My view has an input form where you can type the name or the role of the members you are trying to filter :

**membre2.blade.php:**

```
<form action="/profilecontroller/membrevis" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="filter" >
    <button type="submit">filter</button>
</form> 

@foreach($users as $users) 

   <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $users->name }}</h4>

@endforeach
```

The error i'm getting is `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$name`

I have no idea why i'm getting this error i'm obviously passing $users to my view with this line of command:

```
return view('membre2',['users'=> $users]);
```

Any help would be appreciated! thank you

Comment: @foreach($users as $user) then {{ $user->name }}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when using **$users->get()** it returns **Collection** instance, you must be assign **$users = $users->get()**; Corrected code is

```
    public function membrevis()
    {
        $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ? $_GET['filter'] : null;
        // also can use this structure $filter = isset($_GET['filter']) ?? null;
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
            ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
            ->where('users.valid','=',0)
            ->select('users.*','roles.description');
        if ($filter != null) {
            $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
                ->orWhere('roles.description',' like','%'.$filter.'%');
        }
        $users = $users->get();

        return view('membre2',['users'=> $users]); 
    }
```

also in blade fix it

```
@foreach($users as $user) 

   <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $user->name }}</h4>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you try my answer??

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I did exactly what you wrote and it fixed my problem there!! but the function still doesnt seem to work i have no idea why whenever i filter a name or a role name it doesnt return anything, can you tell me what to do?

Comment: what is a $filter value??

Comment: it can be a user name or a user role name

Comment: Without  $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
                ->orWhere('roles.description',' like','%'.$filter.'%'); what is dd($users->toArray());

Comment: Are you sure this is command line correct dd($users->toArray()); because it shows me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING)

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_role', 'users.id', '=', 'user_role.user_id')
            ->join('roles', 'user_role.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
            ->where('users.valid','=',0)
            ->select('users.*','roles.description');

Comment: $users = $users ->get();

then dd($users ->toArray());

Comment: Hi @Davit this is what i get array:11 [▼
  0 => {#374 ▶}
  1 => {#372 ▶}
  2 => {#373 ▶}
  3 => {#376 ▶}
  4 => {#375 ▶}
  5 => {#377 ▶}
  6 => {#370 ▶}
  7 => {#378 ▶}
  8 => {#379 ▶}
  9 => {#380 ▶}
  10 => {#381 ▶}
]

Comment: @H.tay when using  $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
                ->orWhere('roles.description',' like','%'.$filter.'%'); and after it dd($users->toArray()); If result is empty that means  in your database no record correspond your criteria.

Comment: This is the error im getting: Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray does not exist.

Comment: $users = $users->get(), and after it dd($users->toArray());

Comment: [] just these empty brackets that i'm getting

Comment: That means in your db does not record where 'users.valid','=',0, and  users.name is $filter or roles.description is $filter

Comment: But whatever i type there is really that name or that role description in my db, what do i do??

Comment: show me 2 result without $users->where('users.name','like','%'.$filter.'%')
                ->orWhere('roles.description',' like','%'.$filter.'%'); **dd($users->first()->toArray())**, adn **dd($filter)**;

Comment: I wont to see separate user info and filter value

Comment: "Admin" is what i get after pasting dd($filter);

Comment: it's my request that i wrote in my input in the view

Comment: in users table has record where name is contain 'Admin' word or in roles table has record where description is contain 'Admin' word